# A real unitary matrix is orthogonal, so we have the orthogonality condition?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum

[image]

In Sakurai's Quantum mechanics 2ed p.224 there is the expression like that.
What is the meaning of that sentense? I totally cannot understand..

Comment: Please do not post formulae as screenshots, but use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136) instead.  Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 1):

The Clebsch-Gordan coefficients $\langle j_1j_2;m_1m_2\vert j_1j_2;jm\rangle$ are entries in a matrix that expresses $\vert j_1j_2;jm\rangle$ as linear combinations of $\vert j_1j_2;m_1m_2\rangle$ states.  This matrix is orthogonal so that summing products of distinct columns or rows gives $0$.

The simplest way to see this equality is to note that CGs are real so
$\langle j_1j_2;m_1’m_2’\vert j_1j_2;jm\rangle=\langle j_1j_2;jm\vert j_1j_2;m_1’m_2’\rangle$ and thus
\begin{align}
\sum_{j,m}\langle j_1j_2;m_1m_2\vert j_1j_2;jm\rangle\langle j_1j_2;jm\vert j_1j_2;m_1m_2\rangle=
\sum_{j,m}\langle j_1j_2;m_1m_2\vert j_1j_2;m_1m_2\rangle=\delta_{m_1m_1’}\delta_{m_2m_2’}
\end{align}
since
\begin{align}
\sum_{j,m}\vert j_1j_2;jm\rangle\langle j_1j_2;jm\vert =\mathbb{I}
\end{align}
on the space of product states of angular momentum $j_1$ and $j_2$.